# add and remove item to qx.ui.list.List

Tags: qooxdoo

How can I add item at the end of this array? I didn't find examples. Did I miss something. How can I remove an element?

```
var rawData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
 rawData[i] = "Item " + i;
}
var model = qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel(rawData);

var list = new qx.ui.list.List(model);
//var list = new qx.ui.list.List(new qx.data.Array("item 0"));
//list.add( new qx.ui.list.List("itme 2"))
//list.createItem("item 2")
//list.insertAt(0, "item2")
this.getRoot().add(list);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *MVC* pattern implementation in qooxdoo. The elegant way is to work with model not view. You can wrap JS array by qooxdoo array `qx.data.Array` instead of `qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel`. The qooxdoo array  has method **append** which add to the end of array and remove the last element is **pop** method.

```
const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  data[i] = "Item " + i;
}

const model = new qx.data.Array(data);
const list = new qx.ui.list.List(model);
// removing element from list
model.pop();
// adding element to end of list
model.append("Item 3");

this.getRoot().add(list);

let doc = this.getRoot();
doc.add(list, {left: 100, top: 50});
```

Answer (score 1):

I can use list.getModel().insertAt(2, "item 3")
list.getModel().removeAt(0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).